# Undersampling for multilabel imbalanced datasets in pandas

Tags: pandas, data-science, imblearn

I'm working on a roll-your-own undersampling function, since `imblearn` does not work neatly with multi-label classification (e.g. it only accepts one dimensional `y`).

I want to iterate through X and y, removing a row every 2 or 3 rows that are part of the majority class. The goal is a quick and dirty way to reduce the number of rows in the majority class.

```
def undersample(X, y):
    counter = 0
    for index, row in y.itertuples():
        if row['rectangle_here'] == 0:
            counter += 1
            if counter > 3:
                counter = 0
                X.drop(index, inplace=True)
                y.drop(index, inplace=True)
    return X, y
```

But it crashes my kernel on even a small amount of rows (~30,000).

`y` is something like this, where anytime `f2` or `f3` is present, `f1` is present

So, let's count the number of times 0 happens in `f1` and then delete a 0 row every 3rd time:

```
                  f1      f2       f3
0                  0       0       0
1                  0       0       0
2                  0       0       0
3                  1       0       1
4                  0       0       0
5                  0       0       0
6                  0       0       0
7                  0       0       0
8                  0       0       0
9                  0       0       0
```

Comment: first this:  `new_index = df[df.f1==0][::3].index.append(df[df.f1==0][1::3].index).append(df[df.f1==1].index )`

Comment: and then:  `df.loc[ new_index ].sort_index()`

Comment: thanks @JohnE, this did not work for me though. Not sure why. It doesn't even fail -- it just doesn't seem to do anything! Maybe we need a `.drop` after that...?

Comment: you might need `df=df.loc ... `?